Getting 3 monitor setup to work in ubuntu 24.04 kernel 6.9
I've got a three monitor setup which was working in 22.04.  One external monitor runs from an HDMI output and the other through a USB-C DP output and a USB-HDMI converter. After moving to 24.04 kernel 6.9 the  USB-C is fine. The HDMI monitor is recognized by the display settings GUI and a desktop shows up there but the mouse won't travel to this monitor and thus its unusable, no matter the displays setup.   Same bad behavior in kernel 6.7.3.  Some system info below:
$ xrandr|grep connected
eDP-2 connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 210mm
DP-2 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 400mm
HDMI-1 connected 2560x1440+5120+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: 82TD Legion 7 16IAX7 
Kernel: 6.9.0-060900-generic 
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i9-12900HX (24) @ 4.900GHz 
GPU: Intel Alder Lake-HX GT1 [UHD Graphics 770] 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti Laptop GPU 

and
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA103M [GeForce RTX 3080 Ti Laptop GPU]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=2560x1600 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:640-63f irq:215 memory:83000000-83ffffff memory:6000000000-63ffffffff memory:6400000000-6401ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:84000000-8407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-HX GT1 [UHD Graphics 770]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=2560,1600
       resources: iomemory:640-63f iomemory:400-3ff irq:234 memory:6402000000-6402ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

$ nvidia-smi
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.78                 Driver Version: 550.78

Some dmesg output:
jr@jr-Legion-7-16IAX7:~$ sudo dmesg|grep  -E "video|hdmi|DP|nvidia|display"
[    0.821058] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR DPC]
[    1.350318] UDP hash table entries: 32768 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    1.350422] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 32768 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    1.350493] NET: Registered PF_XDP protocol family
[    1.371801] ACPI: AC: AC Adapter [ADP0] (on-line)
[    1.851817] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.851822] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.851825] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.851825] nvidia: module license taints kernel.
[    1.931848] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
[    1.932642] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    1.932719] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    1.988237] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  550.78  Sun Apr 14 06:23:31 UTC 2024
[    1.990274] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    2.903041] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DP-4
[    2.912134] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DP-4
[    3.050734] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    4.839665] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    4.870767] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 234.
[    5.467510] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input17
[    5.467563] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input18
[    5.467600] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input19
[    5.467630] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input20
[    5.838219] ACPI: video: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    5.838235] ACPI: video: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    5.839198] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    6.156818] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card1/input25
[    6.156841] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card1/input26
[    6.156862] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card1/input27
[    6.156886] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card1/input28
[75287.597147] workqueue: nv_drm_handle_hotplug_event [nvidia_drm] hogged CPU for >10000us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND


Using the nvidia-settings GUI, switching to PRIME Profiles->NVIDIA(Performance Mode) and rebooting seems to have done the trick.
